# Storing dask dataframes to parquet when data doesn't fit in memory

Tags: dask, parquet

I'm trying to store the content of a dask dataframe to parquet. The content is read from a database using `read_sql_table`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_sql_table(table, uri, index_col)
df.to_parquet(path)
```

When I do this, first all the data is first read into memory. But as the entire data set doesn't fit into memory, the kernel will eventually crash. How can I chunk or pipe the data so that this operation will succeed?

(I'm using fastparquet as engine, but not married to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Dask doesn't intend to read the entire dataset into memory.  It starts reading chunks that it expects to be about 256MiB in size, and then stores those chunks into Parquet.  If you have many threads and not so much memory, or if Dask's estimate of how large a chunk is is wrong, then it might be mis-calculating.

You might consider reducing the chunk size with the `bytes_per_chunk=` parameter of the `read_sql_table` function

Comment: I have about 25 GB of free memory when I start, but it ticks down to 0 as I run `to_parquet`, until the kernel dies. Nothing is being written to file before the kernel dies. I've also tried to explicitly set `bytes_per_chunk=268435456`, but to no avail. So it looks to me as no chunking is happening at all.

Comment: You might try using a smaller chunksize than the default.